# Unable to checkin linux format file from windows

Tags: git

Step 1: Run `dos2unix file*`

```
      Result : files converted to linux format on two files.
```

Step 2: run `git status`

```
       Result : Two files with changes in shown.
```

Step 3: Run `git add .`

> Note: After this, git starts ignoring lf and crlf changes.

```
 Result : warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file1.sh.The file will have its original line endings in your working directory warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in file2.sh.The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

Step 4: Run `git status`

```
  Result : Your branch is up to date. Noting to commit
```

Step 5: Repeat step 1 and step 2.

```
  Result : same as step 4
```

Step 6: Try after running `git config  core.autocrlf false`

```
 Result: Problem is not resolved.
```

**Below is sceenshot of the steps.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

The explanation is a little tricky though.  You need to be aware that when you use Git, there are always *three* version of each active file.

The reason that two of these versions exist is obvious enough with a bit of thought.  The third one is a bit odd; we'll get to that in a moment.

Start with the fact that each commit, as identified by its unique hash ID, stores a full snapshot of all of your files.  This inside-a-commit snapshot stores the files in a special, read-only, Git-only format.  Only Git can actually *use* these files.  The special Git format causes de-duplication, so if you have the *same versions* of some file(s) in multiple commits, there's really only one copy of that file.  That's why it's not a big deal that *every* commit has a full copy of *every* file: they're all *shared* whenever possible.  Since each file is frozen for all time, it's easy to share it.

But because these copies of files literally *can't* be changed, and *can't* be used by any other non-Git program on your computer, they are no good for doing work.  They are only useful as archived commits.  So when you use `git checkout` (or `git switch` in Git 2.23 or later), you pick one commit that you'd like to have "checked out".  Git *copies* all of the files from that commit, turning them from special, read-only, Git-only frozen files into regular everyday read/write files, in your computer's normal file format.

The copies that Git puts into normal everyday format, that you can see and work with, are in a work-space area.  Git calls this your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  Since these *are* ordinary files, you can use them, and even change them whenever you like.

So that's why there are two copies of each file in use: there's the frozen one in the *current commit*, and there's the normal-format one in your work-tree.  But what about that third copy?  This copy is in what Git calls its *index*, or the *staging area* (two terms for the same thing).  This one sort of sits in between the frozen `HEAD`-commit copy, and the work-tree copy.

Let's draw a simple illustration of the three copies, assuming you have just two files named `README.md` and `main.py`:

```
   HEAD         index       work-tree
---------     ---------     ---------
README.md     README.md     README.md
main.py       main.py       main.py
```

All three copies of, say, `main.py` match—well, sort of—at the beginning, right after your initial `git checkout`.  The `HEAD` one, the one in the current commit, is frozen: it literally cannot be changed.  The work-tree copy is yours to do with as you like.

The one in between is the one that Git will put in the *next* commit you make.  Right now, it matches the other two.  But what if you *change* `main.py`?  Let's add a version-number to each file:

```
   HEAD         index       work-tree
---------     ---------     ---------
README.md(1)  README.md(1)  README.md(1)
main.py(1)    main.py(1)    main.py(2)
```

You *changed* the work-tree copy, so we bumped the version number.  (It's not actually in the file, we're just drawing it to keep track of what each copy looks like.)

If you want your changed `main.py` to go into your *next* commit, you must now run `git add main.py`.  This copies the `main.py` file into Git's index, *replacing* the existing one.  The new copy is in Git's frozen *format*, but isn't actually frozen yet:

```
   HEAD         index       work-tree
---------     ---------     ---------
README.md(1)  README.md(1)  README.md(1)
main.py(1)    main.py(2)    main.py(2)
```

... but now, after `git add`, the copy in the index is different from the `HEAD` copy (and is the same as the work-tree copy).  If you run `git commit` now, Git will make a new frozen commit from the index copies of each file.

#### Notice that the copies are index → work-tree and work-tree → index

When Git extracts the commit initially, it needs the frozen-format files in its index.  That's easy and is a straight copy.<sup>1</sup>  Git needs to copy that frozen-format file to your work-tree, though, and this involves de-compressing and de-Git-izing it.  Git makes this copy by extracting the index version (frozen-format) to your work-tree (a regular everyday file):

- index → work-tree: de-compress

Meanwhile, your later `git add` has to copy your work-tree file into the index:

- work-tree → index: compress into frozen format

What if, while Git is doing these copies, we gave Git the ability to turn Unix / Linux style LF-only line endings into Windows-style CRLF line endings?  Then we just need this:

- index → work-tree: de-compress and Windows-ify
- work-tree → index: de-Windows-ify and re-compress

and that's what Git does, when you tell it to manipulate line endings.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, it's even easier, because the index doesn't hold a true *copy* of the file, but rather a reference to an internal Git *blob object*.  But you don't need to worry about this—not unless you get down into the details of using `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index`, anyway.

---

#### What you did

You started out, and ran for some number of commits so far, with `core.autocrlf` set to `true`.  This tells Git: *do mess with my line endings*.  The files Git modifies are, by default, the ones it guesses are the right ones to have this done to them.  (It's usually wiser to use `.gitattributes` to tell Git which files should be manipulated like this, rather than letting Git guess, but Git's guesses are pretty good, most of the time.)

Since Git already does the same de-Windows-line-ending work, the earlier files, committed on Windows, already have Linux-style LF-only line endings.  The index copies, which always literally match the committed copies initially, also have Linux-style LF-only line endings.

**Only your work-tree copies have other kinds of line endings** and even then, they only have those line endings if you told Git to manipulate line endings (which you did).

When you tell Git *don't mess with my line endings at all*, *then* it matters whether your work-tree files have CRLF line endings, or LF-only line endings, because *then* `git add` will copy whatever you have in your work-tree, into Git's index, without messing with any line endings.  Setting `core.autocrlf` to false, and not having any more-explicit settings in `.gitattributes`, does this, so *now* it becomes important to make sure your work-tree files have the endings you want to have in new copies you `git add` and then `git commit`.

You ran `dos2unix` on two work-tree files.  This takes their CR-LF Windows-style line endings, if they had those line endings in the first place (they probably did), and turns them into LF-ony line endings.  Then you ran `git add`.  The `git add` step this time *didn't* de-Windows-ize the line endings, but did re-compress the files.  The result was ... the same file that was already in the index, for each file, because the index copies have been Unix / Linux style all along.

Note that it's now *very important* what line endings you put in each file, because with `core.autocrlf` turned off, and no `.gitattributes` entries, you've told Git: *hands off all file contents: do not mess with line endings.*

If you'd like Git to mess with line endings in a really predictable fashion, rather than guessing, you should create a `.gitattributes` file and list each file name or file-name-pattern and the correct treatment for that file.  This is a bit painful to set up initially, but after that, tends to work well—it's what the Git folks do with the Git project.